# Filter list, order, edit row and return

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here's the situation :

You have a list of items. The list can be paged, filtered and ordered. On every row, an edit button. Click the edit button, go to a page and save.

Now - I would like to go back to the same filters/page as before.

I would also like to make this as generic as possible so it's easy to apply on multiple pages.

Here's what I was thinking:

My action looks like this :

```
public ActionResult Index(StudentFilter studentFilter)
```

Create an attribute which overrides OnActionExecuting. If there are ActionParameters incoming then there probably refiltering the list, so just store the new filter (here I'd like to actually get the StudentFilter object - so ideas on how to get that are welcomed).

If there are no ActionParameters then load the stored filter (maybe from a json serialized cookie) and set it on the Model.

The problem here is that I don't know how to fill the Model.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: For this kind of application I generally just load up a jQuery grid of some sort, and do all of the ordering (and sometimes the filtering also) on the client side.

Comment: I've looked at jQuery grids and I found them a bit of a hassle, I could look into them a bit more in depth thow.

Answer (score 0):

You could think of some kind of base class for filter:

```
public class BaseFilter
{
    public string Property { get; set; } 
    public FilterType Type { get; set; }
    public Object[] Arguments { get; set; }
    public Expression<T> GenerateExpression()
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

Writing `GenerateExpression()` function can be nice exercise:)

You could store `List<BaseFilter>` in Session for current user. Other functionalities will have other session key. When you want to apply filter, you will call:

```
var items = Repository.GetAll();
var filters = Session["key"] as List<BaseFilter>;//Session wrapper usage recommended here
foreach(var filter in filters)
{
    items = items.Where(filter.GenerateExpression());
}
```

If you wan't to store other parameters, you can create additional class and store it in Session instead of `List<BaseFilter>`:

```
public class ListState
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public List<BaseFilter> AppliedFilters { get; set; }
    public string Order { get; set; } 
}
```